# Why does a Sentence parse throw an exception only the first time?

Tags: java, scala, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using the `edu.stanford.nlp.simple` package to generate parse trees for sentences in several different languages. The English and Chinese models produce the expected results, e.g.

```
> val s = new Sentence("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
> s.parse

res1: edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree = (ROOT (NP (NP (DT The) (JJ quick) (JJ brown) (NN fox)) (NP (NP (NNS jumps)) (PP (IN over) (NP (DT the) (JJ lazy) (NN dog))))))
```

(I am using Scala here but that shouldn't make a difference.)

Other languages like German, however, exhibit a strange behavior:

```
> val p = new Properties()
> p.load(IOUtils.readerFromString("StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties"))
> val s = new Sentence("Ich hoffe, dass es funktionieren wird.")
> s.parse(p)

10:48:34.127 [main] INFO  e.s.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/germanFactored.ser.gz ... done  [1.4sec].                                                                                                                                    
java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                                                            
  edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.toProto(ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.java:672)                                                   
  edu.stanford.nlp.simple.Document.runParse(Document.java:933)                                                                                            
  edu.stanford.nlp.simple.Sentence.parse(Sentence.java:637)                                                                                               
  ammonite.$sess.cmd3$.<init>(cmd3.sc:1)                                                                                                                  
  ammonite.$sess.cmd3$.<clinit>(cmd3.sc)

> s.parse(p)
res4: edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree = (ROOT (S (PPER Ich) (VVFIN hoffe) ($, ,) (S (KOUS dass) (PPER es) (VP (VVINF funktionieren)) (VAFIN wird)) ($. .)))
```

I have examined the properties `p` to verify that they haven't changed -- the parser consistently throws a `NullPointerException` on the first invocation and then works correctly afterwards for the same sentence.

I have had a look through the source for CoreNLP but can't find an explicit reason why this might be happening... I wonder if I'm missing something?

I am using Stanford-CoreNLP version `3.9.1`. The foreign language models I'm referencing are the ones from the Maven repository, also discussed on the [Stanford CoreNLP website](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html).

Comment: I think you should add the exact version of the Stanford NLP you use and also the link to the Geman model file you use. It looks like the exception happens during loading of the model but somehow it still can run afterwards anyway.

Comment: @SergGr good idea -- I've edited the original post

Comment: @SergGr I'm not sure it happens when loading the model, either. I can parse the same sentence multiple times and it will throw on the first try. If I create a new `Sentence`, though, it will again fail on the first attempt even though the model has already been initialized.

Comment: This is a bug in the code, I can reproduce it in Java.  I'll look into it...

Comment: I will note a quick fix is to access the dependencyGraph() first, that makes the crash go away...but still this shouldn't happen...

Comment: I'll fix this tomorrow/today!  The bug is actually because there is no converter for German constituency parses to dependency parses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed as a bug -- @StanfordNLPHelp's fix works for me.